# Python Pandas Query for multiple files with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm looking for some advice. I have a basic understanding of Pandas and think this should be easy to implement but don't know how to.

I have uploaded two images below.

[image: file name]

[image: csv format]

I will have a folder weekly that will contain approximately 100 csv files with the format below. Each row denotes a pupil name and the column is the previous 7 days and the filename corresponds to the subject the sheet is for.

I would like a way to concatenate all the csv(dfs) together and filter, so it only shows pupils that have no entries(v) against any columns. The tricky part is that I then need to know what csv that came from, as each csv denotes a different class in the school. my thoughts were to add in a column for each csv df that contains the file name so when I filter all pupils with no data in any of the cells from the 7 days it would also show what file that came from. All csvs would be stores in the same folder relative to the path so I would also like to iterate over the folder to append all file names to a list to make the reading to csv a lot easier.

Apologies, I know that is a lot, if it is unclear I am happy to explain further. Any help would be appreciated.

Update

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the files are in your `Desktop` folder, you can do use `glob` and `concat` all of the files (put in whatever folder path you require in my code). and create a new `Filename` column as you read in the files. Finally, `dropna()` rows passing the subset of the columns starting at column 4:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
files = glob.glob(r'Desktop/*.csv') # or 'Desktop/*.csv' without the 'r'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(Filename=os.path.basename(f)) for f in files])
df = df[df[df.columns[3:-1]].isna().all(axis=1)]
df
```

---

```
#for xlsx files:

import pandas as pd
import os
files = glob.glob(r'Desktop/*.xlsx') # or 'Desktop/*.csv' # or 'Desktop/*.csv' without the 'r'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f).assign(Filename=os.path.basename(f)) for f in files])
df = df[df[df.columns[3:-1]].isna().all(axis=1)]
df
```

Comment: It is coming up with the error, no objects to concatenate. I'm using linux is that perhaps an issue when putting in the file path. Seems to be an issue with the glob.glob when trying to store the file names.

Comment: @Shcoder what folder are you trying to get the files from. If you print "files" with `print(files)`, there should be a list in there.

Comment: the files are stored on my desktop to test it. I think the directory should be files = glob.glob(r'/home/sandy/Desktop/*.csv') but when I print files it displays an empty list.

Comment: Got it. xlxs format instead of csv so managed to create a workaround using openpyxl

Comment: @Shcoder okay you can also use `pd.read_excel()`. See the second part of my answer.

Comment: I used that but the issue is that it has dropped all the NAN. Is there a way to retreive the data of all records with all NAN in those columns. I now have a df with records that have an entry in one of the 7 cells.

Comment: @Shcoder see updated answer. Try: `df = df[df[df.columns[3:]].isna()]`

Comment: Thats great but it has now replaced last name, first name and class with NAN for all those rows, is there a way to amend it, I've added a screenshot

Comment: Perfect. Can I ask all(axis=1) fixes this, just for my learning.

Comment: @Shcoder `all(axis=1)` requres `all` columns to have `NaN` values in order to return `True` for the rows that have all of the nans. `axis=1` means searching across columns. `axis=0` is default and searches across rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help